# Alter comment links in blog teaser in drupal 7

Tags: theming, nodes

I would like to alter the comment links in the teaser view of the blog page. The code I have in node--blog.tpl.php at the moment is:

```
<code><?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
<div class="submitted">
  <ul>
<li><?php $date = date("d F Y", $node->created); ?>
<?php print $date; ?> </li>
 <li> <?php $user = user_load($node->uid); ?>
        <?php $username=$user->name; ?>
<?php print t("By"); ?>
<a href="blogs/<?php print $username ?>"><?php print $username ?> </a> </li>
  <li> <span><?php print ($comment_count); ?></span> <?php print render($content['links']['comment']); ?></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

>

with css: `.submitted ul li span {
        color: #fff;
        background: url("../images/blue-bubble.png") 0px 2px no-repeat;
        background-size: 100% 96%;
        padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
}`

which produces:

[image: Blog - how it looks now]

but I want to make:

[image: Blog - how it should look]

Any suggestions on this would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd hide the span content in CSS and add a tag for my background image like this:

Template:

```
<li>
    <span class="comment-hidden"><?php print ($comment_count); ?></span>
    <span class="comment-count"></span>
    <?php print render($content['links']['comment']); ?>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.submitted ul li span.comment-count { 
  width: 16px; // or whatever
  height: 16px;
  background: url("../images/blue-bubble.png") 0px 2px no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 96%; 
  padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px; 
}

.submitted ul li span.comment-hidden { 
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Djouuuuh but the blue bubble is still sitting above the comment links. The html output wraps the comment links within a new ul.

Comment: Could you paste the generated code here ? I don't get it :/

Comment: <li>
    <span class="comment-hidden">25</span>
    <span class="comment-count"></span>
    <ul class="links list-inline"><li class="comment-comments first"><a href="/blog/blog-entry-two#comments" title="Jump to the first comment of this posting.">25 comments</a></li>
<li class="comment-add last"><a href="/comment/reply/144#comment-form" title="Add a new comment to this page.">Add new comment</a></li>
</ul>    </li> - the generated output

Comment: Just make the inside ul display inline or something. It's only css tricks at this point..

Comment: ul displaying inline has helped. Can live with the comment count being in light blue but initially wanted to make it appear as white inside the dark blue bubble. Thanks for your suggestions :)